# How do I create a query to extract differences between two tables that contain null values?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am writing a query that extracts the differences between a new table and an old table.

```
SELECT New.Entity, New.Type, New.Address, New.Country
FROM tbl_EntityList_New As New
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_EntityList_Old as Old
WHERE New.Entity = Old.Entity
AND New.Address = Old.Address);
```

However, the query seems to mistakenly return blank addresses as a difference. To combat this, I added another portion to the first WHERE clause as so:

```
SELECT New.Entity, New.Type, New.Address, New.Country
FROM tbl_EntityList_New As New
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tbl_EntityList_Old as Old
WHERE New.Entity = Old.Entity
AND New.Address = Old.Address)
AND New.Address Is Not Null;
```

However, new records with blank addresses will be excluded from this query, and I have no influence over how users enter in their new records.

How can I amend my SQL to extract the differences I need? Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
SELECT New.Entity, New.Type, New.Address, New.Country
FROM tbl_EntityList_New As New
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tbl_EntityList_Old as Old
                  WHERE New.Entity = Old.Entity AND
                        ( New.Address = Old.Address OR
                          New.Address IS NULL AND Old.Address IS NULL
                        );
```